# current supervisor vs. previous work

Tags: publications, supervision

My M.Sc. Thesis' abstract got accepted for presentation at a conference this year and I am about to send the paper. Should I give the paper to my current supervisor (of my Ph.D. in a different University) to read it and have an opinion?

**EDIT: Including answers to comments**

My previous supervisor has read it and gave me feedback. He suggested me sending the abstract and his relationship with my current supervisor does not exist since they don't know each other.

Comment: That's up to you and him, really. Has your previous supervisor already looked it over?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. As it stands your question is very broad or unclear, respectively. What are your goals and concerns? Do you need additional feedback? What feedback did you already get? Why do you think you should not do this? What is the relation between your new and old supervisor, their areas of expertise, and your topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have feedback from your previous supervisor (who presumably knows the research in question much better since it was done with him) it's not critical to get feedback from your new advisor. But any feedback can be useful, especially if your new advisor is in the same area.

I would at least make your new advisor aware of the paper and ask if they want to read it, just so there won't be any surprises or perceptions that you are publishing "behind their back". Leave it up to them if they want to give you feedback or not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's your current supervisor's job to coach you.